# How can I create a custom variable to use it in my layout template page?

Tags: 7, theming

For my new project, I'm using the brand new Omega4 theme. It comes with a lot of cool and nice features build in, so no complain about that!

But when I try to use a custom variable in my `theme-layout.tpl.php` with the `hook_preprocess_html()`, nothing is passed...

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_variable'] = 'My New Variable';
}
```

When I try to access my new variable in my `theme-layout.tpl.php` page with `<?php print render($page['my_variable']); ?>`, nothing is appearing.

Although, if I `dpm` my `$variables` in both my template and my `html.preprocess.inc` file, the `dpm` in my template is printed first... So it looks like the template is printed first and then the preprocess hook is called.

How can I create a custom variable to use it in my layout template page?

Comment: I'm not making an answer as I have no experience with omega, however THEMENAME_preprocess_html() goes with html.tpl.php. I don't know what theme-layout.tpl.php is. Normally I would expect theme-layout.tpl.php to use THEMENAME_preprocess_theme_layout() or similar. Although I know omega theme does some pretty wild things so I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is right but this has less to do with omega than with the [order in which Drupal is preprocessing your hook](https://drupal.org/node/223430). The html template hook is too late in the process, this is just for [rendering the html wrapper](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) and already assumes the existing variables. Instead, following the 1st handbook link above, use the base preprocess hook to establish your variables, ex:

```
function theme_preprocess(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_variable'] = 'My New Variable';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the preprocess function you used in your answer is the same as in my question, no? I do need to replace `theme` with the machine name of my theme, right?

Comment: sorry - did that too fast, i meant use the hook_preprocess function which works first, corrected above.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong here... Still cannot access `print render($page['my_variable']);`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is how you're printing the variable.

Instead of:

```
<?php print render($page['my_variable']); ?>
```

Do this:

```
<?php print render($my_variable); ?>
```

You only need the render() function if your variable is a renderable array. So you most likely only need:

```
<?php print $my_variable; ?>
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense... And in which preprocessor should I use this?